# How to define sensible sass placeholder

Tags: html, css, sass

### Background

I am a junior front-end developer and recently started using sass.

### Question

Am I doing it the right way when I create, for example, `%main-text-color` placeholder and extend it where necessary?

I think this kind of approach decreases repetition in the CSS files and helps to keep the CSS **DRY**.

Comment: Generally this forum is for asking questions on specific problems, not asking for other's opinions on your approach.

Comment: I believe I asked a question

Comment: "What is your favorite background color?" is also a question, that doesn't mean it is on-topic.

Comment: READ CAREFULLY  "Is it a right way for example create  %main-text-color placeholder and extend it where necessary?"
When you read this second or third time anyway you don't understand that is a question related to SASS and on-topic?

Comment: What's "right" or "wrong" is a matter of opinion, that's the problem here, not the fact that you're asking about Sass.  On top of that, you didn't bother doing *any* research at all (funny the kinds of results you get when you google for "sass extend" or "sass extend best practice").

Comment: Heey did somebody feel bed about my question????   I know where  and how to research articles which interested me.  Instead of did lot of  inappropriate comments I think it would be better to write something useful related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Nooooo....  you want to create a variable for the color, and use the variable when needed.

`$main-text-color: #333;`

Comment: OK, but in which situation can help placeholder?

Comment: Placeholders work best when you have a set of styles that are specific to a component. Think of an element such as a button.  Placeholders can define a set of rules as base styles, and then you could extend those into other buttons.  I'd suggest reading up on the subject.  A simple google search will give you a ton of articles on placeholders, mixins, and just general Sass best practices.